# nav[role="navigation"].dark is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have created a JS function for toggle of dark theme and light theme everything is working but this nav one is not working

```
nav[role="navigation"].dark{
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
```

And my Javascript

```
document.getElementById("dark").addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark')
    localStorage.setItem(
      'theme',
      document.body.classList.contains('dark') ? 'dark' : 'light'
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `dark` class is apply to the body your selector probably sould be `.dark nav[role="navigation"]` and not `nav[role="navigation"].dark`

```
.dark nav[role="navigation"] {
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
}
```